# possible way to remove square thing in my picture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photo-editing, image-editing

ok so I found this image and want to change its color

[image]

but when I tried to change its color, this happened

[image]

I did everything, I blurred it (surface and smart blur), I reduced the noise and still nothing
can anyone tell me what is the problem and also help me out on it

Comment: Yes your image is jpeg compressed. Jpeg is a delivery formatnot a editing format so you should strive to avoid using jpegs for editing, always store the original. Theres not much you can do beyond recreating the image.

Comment: I'd merely recreate it...... Better end result, and actually *less* work.

Answer (score 2):

Those little squares are called jpeg artefacts, and they're caused by excessive jpeg compression. Removal of jpeg artefacts can be difficult, although you might be able to find third party plugins to do it. The best approach I think is to avoid the problem by colourising the image in a different way.

1. Create a Hue-Saturation Adjustment Layer, and set the *Colorize* option, then change the hue saturation and lightness sliders to get a lighter blue.
2. With a large soft edged Brush, set the opacity of the brush to about 50%, foreground colour black, Select the layer mask, and paint on it to reveal the original darker blue only on side.
3. If it's not quite right you can paint on the mask with white as the foreground colour to reveal more of the light blue colour.

Example

[image]

4. If you want more of a three-tone effect you can stack up hue-saturation adjustment layers and again edit the masks to reveal the colours just in the areas you want.

Example: here I've added a lighter green hue-saturation adjustment, and edited the masks so that it just applies to the top right corner.

[image]

Comment: show me the link for the plugin please

Comment: @user3556983 I said you might be able to find a plugin, not that there was a plugin. In any case, you don't need a plugin at all if you do it the way I showed.

Answer (score 0):

If me, first I changes the image document (300 DPI for sure) [image]

Then, I used magic wand to select blue color and pressed ctrl+shift+j (layer via cut)

and then I put color overlay (or you can use gradient) and add a little stroke on bottom layer

[image]

Comment: Why would resampling do anything useful here?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what u meant @joojaa

Comment: Why would resampling the image to 300 dpi do anything useful.

Comment: @joojaa you can try selection tool with 72dpi and 300dpi, and you will see 300dpi and resize to bigger file doing better than 72dpi do

Comment: No not really. Because you have blurred the edges the tolerance value changes but its still just one option